# extruding 3 faces to get a wall

Tags: modeling

i´m totally new to blender, so i want to learn the basics as good as possible.

My problem: I want to make just a simple Studio background with 1 floor and 2 walls by extruding 3 faces of a cube. (cube, delete 1 vertex, select 3 faces and extrude).
When i do so, the new walls are slanted or their origin is just 45° below the old origin.
I found a workaround: setting the 3d cursor to the first deleted vertex and then extruding the walls by 0, then scaling the new walls with my 3d cursor as center. But i want to do it just by extruding.
what am i doing/thinking wrong?

[image: slanted walls when extruding]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in the upper left corner when you are doing the Extrude Along Normals you will see that you can change the behaviour. In this case you can press S or Alt to get Even Thickness.

[image]

Even Thickness is also an option in the Solidify Modifier.

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot. that worked very well!
It also works with the solidifier - i just did something wrong there (wrong pivot...idk)

Answer (score 0):

Extrude doesn't work properly in such cases and you need to use **Snap to** vertices as well. Instead, you can use solidify (a modifier or <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd>) to make the walls and floor thick.

Comment: thanks a lot. wanted to solve the issue without solidifier